# Minimum Margin in Tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Is there a way to do a minimum margin in tailwind similar to w-min, I can't find it in the docs. I am looking for the margin to be 1/5 of the screen but a minimum of 12 (units).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [use arbitary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) to specify the `max()` value.

e.g.) According to your spec, `1/5` of the screen is `20vw` (or `20vh` for height). and 12 units (guessing in pixels?) as `12px`.

If you do, `mx-[max(20vw,12px)]`, it will generate the following rule,

```css
.mx-\[max\(20vw\2c 12px\)\] {
  margin-left: max(20vw,12px);
  margin-right: max(20vw,12px);
}
```

[max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) lets you choose whichever is bigger.
So if `20vw` is less than `12px`, then `12px` margin will be used, and vice versa.

You can use all variations of margin utilities such as `m-*`, `my-*`, `m[lrtb]-*` as well.

Comment: `m-12` in tailwind means 48px, clean answer btw! +1

Comment: whoa, I did not know this was possible, if you don't mind could you link docs to this follow rule type stuff so I can read more?

Comment: Radical stuff it sure it @MichaelThomas : ).  Follow the link in the answer [use arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) for more info. Just be aware of not using spaces in between because "spaces" are significant in CSS. In my example, there is no space next to the comma  in `mx-[max(20vw,12px)]`.

Comment: ty @Dhaifallah for the info on `m-12` and the compliment!

Comment: Thank you for the awesome response, it really helped out!

Comment: Unsure how your CSS is structured, @Qwerty, what I can suggest is a minum height using arbitrary value https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height#arbitrary-values